# Calling C++ function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

I try to link `QWebEngineView` with JavaScript file by using `QWebChannel`
this is my HTML file (`qmapview` declared in `mapapi.js`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/mapapi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

function load()
{
    if (typeof qt !== 'undefined')
    new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {
        qmapview = channel.objects.qmapview;
        if (qmapview.isEarthAvailable()) {
            google.load("earth", "1", {"language": "en", "other_params":"sensor=false"});
        }
    } );

    showDiv(document.getElementById("map"));
    hideDiv(document.getElementById("earth"));

    mapi.init(document.getElementById("map"));
    mapi.panorama.init();

    traffic.init();
    directions.init();
}

//]]>
</script>
```

and this is registering of object

```
 m_webChannel = new QWebChannel();
    m_webpage->setWebChannel(m_webChannel);
    m_webChannel->registerObject("qmapview", this) ;
```

i would like to call function of object from js file(something like this `qmapview.mapZoomChanged();)`, but don't now to do it in my case.

I have read about Q_Property but didn't understand.

In debug something like this:

```
Property 'visible'' of object 'MapWidget' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'minimized'' of object 'MapWidget' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'maximized'' of object 'MapWidget' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'fullScreen'' of object 'MapWidget' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
```

Comment: Here is detailed documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-javascript.html

Comment: i did all according to this documentation

Comment: We have the same issue but after "a client must use and set up the JavaScript API provided by qwebchannel.js. For clients run inside Qt WebEngine, you can load the file via qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js. For external clients, you need to copy the file to your web server." problem solved for us.

Comment: Also take a look at Q_INVOKABLE macro. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE

Comment: @MherDidaryan can you say what path you selected.
i set this:<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Qt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/msvc2015/include/QtWebChannel/5.8.0/QtWebChannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
it exist i checked, but does not work

Comment: i think my problem in does not existing of this file or bad path